# publish html plugin: violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, extentreports, extent

Hi I'm using jenkins and i have generate report in the end of automation run, after the run the jenkins generate publish html directory to the job folder that I can see the current log report, but I got some error

> ExtentScreenshot.html:1 The source list for Content Security Policy
>   directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''allow-scripts''.
>   It will be ignored. ExtentScreenshot.html:22 Refused to load the
>   stylesheet
>   'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ".
>
> ExtentScreenshot.html:23 Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/45123d736a03aca0abc5c4fcf1e746fef49736fd/cdn/extent.css'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ".
>
> ExtentScreenshot.html:1 Refused to load the script
>   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/6032d73243ba4fe4fb8769eb9c315d4fdf16fe68/cdn/extent.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'allow-scripts'".
>
> ExtentScreenshot.html:695 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at ExtentScreenshot.html:695 ExtentScreenshot.html:699 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at ExtentScreenshot.html:699 ExtentScreenshot.html:1 Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ".
>
> ExtentScreenshot.html:1 Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/45123d736a03aca0abc5c4fcf1e746fef49736fd/cdn/extent.css'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ".

as I use in others reports in my jenkins I have to change the jenkins.xml file in the line

> -Xrs -Xmx1048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
>   -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle "-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= img-src 'self'; style-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
>   'allow-scripts' " -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=2020
>   --webroot="%BASE%\war"--accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger
>   --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file="%BASE%/logs/access.log"

what should be the current configuration in jenkins to allow my view the report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable CSP at all by setting `Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=` to empty string.
See   [Configuring Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy), [CSP directives](https://content-security-policy.com/)

Comment: @AakashPahuja why do you you think so? This approach is still described in the current doc I reference.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko, I upgraded HtmlPublisher, and now extent reports got disturbed. I used your suggestion, but it was failing. So I figured out to solve it. And now I can load proper and good looking extent reports with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

If you just updated HTML Publisher, Please run this script in Jenkins console.

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```